# Virtualize Multiple instances

Tags: vps, multiple-instances, linux-terminal

I have this problem, I want open multiple instances of a portable software named hitleap (it is for ubuntu, I am not using wine) in ubuntu.

when I try open after is running the shows me
[image]

How could I running multiple instances of the this program?

**I want not VirtualMachines as virtualbox because I have low ram and processor (This ubuntu is a VPS)**

NOTE: please do not suggest me networking solutions, my problem is that the program denied to execute more of one instance of self

**IF someone want try resolve the problem, please download the files, in the web page [Link of app only for ubuntu 64 bits linux](https://hitleap.com/viewer/download?platform=Linux) and testing.**

Answer (score 0):

The [HitLeap Support page](https://hitleap.com/support) says :

> **Can I run multiple HitLeap Viewers?**
>
> Yes, if you have access to multiple computers then you can run one
>   instance of the HitLeap Viewer on each of them, assuming that they
>   also have different IP addresses.

This means that only one instance is allowed for each IP address,
so you cannot run more than one instance on one computer.

**The VirtualBox solution**

The simple solution would be to use [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) to create multiple virtual
machines that can each run one separate instance of HitLeap.
This simple solution is not very convenient, but does not require deep
knowledge of Linux.

**The network namespaces solution (without VirtualBox)**

More complex solutions that do not require virtual machines are described in the post
[Bind unix program to specific network interface](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210982/bind-unix-program-to-specific-network-interface).

The accepted answer uses a flexible feature called 'network namespaces'
which is exposed through the `ip` program of Linux.
The answer describes doing the following as root:

> ```
> # Add a new namespace called test_ns
> ip netns add test_ns
>
> # Set test to use eth0, after this point eth0 is not usable by programs
> # outside the namespace
> ip link set eth0 netns test_ns
>
> # Bring up eth0 inside test_ns
> ip netns exec test_ns ip link set eth0 up
>
> # Use dhcp to get an ipv4 address for eth0
> ip netns exec test_ns dhclient eth0
>
> # Ping google from inside the namespace
> ip netns exec test_ns ping www.google.co.uk
> ```
>
> It is also possible to manage network namespaces to some extent with
>   the `unshare` and `nsenter` commands. This allows you to also create
>   separate spaces for PIDs, users and mount points.

Further references contained in that post are :

- [Reliable way to jail child processes using nsenter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124162/reliable-way-to-jail-child-processes-using-nsenter/124194)
- [Namespaces in operation](https://lwn.net/Articles/531114/)

Comment: thank you for you reply, I understand it, I have 4 virtual marchines with proxys for it (In my pc). but the problem it that I have a VPS i want run multiples instances without virtual machinas as virtualbox because I have not good processor in my VPS... I need can run multiples instances in the ubuntu of the VPS...

Comment: That depends if you can use network namespaces on the VPS.

Comment: Really I could use proxychains for solved it. The problem is that the problem can not be opened in more of one instance

Comment: Proxychains only present an IP address to an external server. A program launched from inside the computer sees the real IP address associated with the default network interface. If the computer has multiple network interfaces then programs can be bound to them and therefore use differing IP addresses - this is also described in my above link, but the network namespaces method is easier to use.

Comment: Thank you, but it don't solve the problem for open multiple instances in the software.

Comment: Why doesn't it solve the problem?

Comment: Because I cant open multiple instances of the app without virtualbox. I need open with multiple instances, the networking problem are from another section

Comment: Please understand that there are two parts to my answer. VirtualBox is only the first part. The part using network namespaces does not use at all VirtualBox. With network namespaces you can have as many instances of a program running - each with its own IP address. This is a Linux feature and does not use VirtualBox.